# Layout using Bootstrap not aligning correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, screen-layout

I have been stuck at a strange layout alignment issue. I have been using Bootstrap 4 to set layout of a section. Please take a look at the screenshot below -

[image]
This is [here](https://www.xn--smslneguide-08a.se/).
It is working as expected. Now, check [here](https://www.mobil-lan.se/) -

[image]

The exact same plugin breaking on another WordPress installation. This type of issue usually occurs due to the styling on an enclosing wrapper but couldn't find anything. I have been banging my head over it for the last couple of days but could not pin point the issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Should the second link be to a URL where it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work in the second URL

Comment: URLs are the same.

Comment: Apologies.
Correct - https://www.xn--smslneguide-08a.se/
Incorrect - https://www.mobil-lan.se/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to box-sizing

Bootstrap expects `box-sizing` to be `border-box` to work properly, however in your second link it isn't so.

A quick fix is to add this custom css to your project:

```
.row * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!